# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR::raiseErro() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 165

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-11.04, pear

when running

- pear upgrade

the following error is raised:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR::raiseErro() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 165
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php:0
PHP   2. PEAR_Command_Common->run() /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php:305
PHP   3. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Common.php:271
PHP   4. PEAR_Command_Install->doUpgradeAll() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:547
PHP   5. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:902
PHP   6. PEAR_Command_Install->_filterUptodatePackages() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:619
PHP   7. PEAR_REST_10->listLatestUpgrades() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:1233
PHP   8. PEAR_REST->retrieveData() /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST/10.php:649
```

any suggestions what is causing this?

thanks.

Comment: Running the command as root under OS X was able to fix this problem for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this on Ubuntu 10.04 installing the Mongo PHP-extension.
Did some research and tried this:

```
# pear search http
The value of config option cache_dir (/tmp/pear/cache) is not a directory and attempts to 
create the directory failed.
```

When I created the directories by hand:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/pear/cache
```

the error "went away" and I was able to install: "pecl install mongo".